# how to use which.min in subset of data frame?

Tags: r

I have this data frame

```
df <- structure(list(a = 1:20, b = c(4, 2, 5, 6, 2, 4, 7, 4, 9, 7, 6, 1, 1, 5, 2, 1, 9, 8, 6, 3), c = c(340, 200, 130, 730, 710, 340, 200, 130, 730, 710, 340, 200, 130, 730, 710, 340, 200, 130, 730, 710)), .Names = c("a", "b", "c"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

My desired output is the index of

```
which.min(df[1:V,3])
```

where V is a row number, e.g.

```
V <- 10
```

However, I'd like the following restriction:

```
df[which(df$a<=df$b[V]),]
```

I think I've tried any combinition to bring these together (e.g. with `with()`) but I just cannot get it to work. What do I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
which.min(with(df, df[a<=b[V],])[1:V,3])
#[1] 3
```

Comment: Nevermind, I got it, I overwrote my real data frame with the example and then everything got mixed up, it works now! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually, I just realised that I have the following problem: `which.min()` of course returns the index, but in the subsetted data frame this does not correspond to the row name (as it does in my original data frame), as I use this index to then refer to a certain row in my original data frame this is not working. Is there a way to return the row name instead of the index? Or would I have to turn row names into a column and go from there?

Comment: @beetroot you dont have rownames in your sample data, so perhaps you could add that. Otherwise, you could also add an index column to your original data and return the index-column-value of the subsetted which.min operation

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table` instead of `data.frame` this can be represented in a much more readable way:

```
library(data.table)
dt = as.data.table(df)

dt[a <= b[V]][1:V, which.min(c)]
#[1] 3
```